# Is there a Visual Studio Code command for Developer: Reload Webviews?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a VSC command that is related to Developer: Reload Webviews?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `workbench.action.webview.reloadWebviewAction` command.

You can confirm this if you open the **Command Palette**, search for the `Developer: Reload Webviews` command and hit the **gear icon** at right. It will open the **Keyboard Shortcuts** panel, filtered with `@command:workbench.action.webview.reloadWebviewAction`.

Hope this helps